# Should i be online to run grade build?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-developer-api

I have just started android and I created an app that was running fine a few days ago now I am working on another app but I am not able to run that and now I’m not even able to run the previous one.
now it's just showing Waiting for all the target devices to come online
and then it says Gradle build finished in 830ms or like that!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> now it's just showing Waiting for all the target devices to come
> online

To solve this-

Go to **Device Manager**>> **Virtual** and select launch AVD or from options select cold boot now.

[image: just like bellow image]

Answer (score 0):

[Like Zobaer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73510757/13598222), if it says *waiting for devices* that usually means the build has completed (you can check that in the *Build* panel) and it's waiting for the emulator to show up. If your emulator is already running, try closing it and running the app again. Otherwise if it's not getting started, try starting it yourself.

I'm just posting an answer to point out that you sometimes *do* need to be online for Gradle to run, but you can put it in *offline mode*:

[image: The Gradle panel with the offline-mode toggle highlighted]

That button in the popout panel, or you can always do Ctrl+Shift+A as usual and start typing what you're looking for!